# Bootstrap-select not expanding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-select

I am facing problems with dropdown of selectpicker. I am not able to get the dropdown menu when i click on .
Following are my files:

View:

```
<div class="form-group set-up-down">
            <%= f.label :pricing_style_id %><br>
            <%= f.select 'pricing_style_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@labs_pricing_style, :id, :name),{:include_blank => '-Choose Starting Price Sheet-'},class:'selectpicker'%>
            <p id="pricingstyleError" style="display: none; color: red;">Please enter a pricing style for this new pricesheet.</p>
          </div>
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-colorpicker.min
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker.min
//= require bootstrap-select.min
//= require bootstrap-switch
//= require bootstrap-switch.min
//= require bootstrap-tagsinput
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery-1.12.1.min
// require_tree .
```

application.css:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

Any help will be appreciated. thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. So... what have you tried yoruself to solve this problem? What do you mean by "not working"? (can you be specific and give us a concrete example of what you observe, and what you expected to observe instead)? Can you copy the broken html/js and put it into a fiddle for us to play with?

Comment: When i click on the <select> that contains the class "selectpicker", it do not show any dropdown menu.

Comment: Hi Vishal, I guess what I'm trying to say is: there isn't enough information in your question to help you yet. Have a read of our guide to writing a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   and please edit your question and add in the extra information that we need. Please follow the guidelines or we actually can't help you. Not because we don't want to, but because there isn't enough information to go on.